# What's the difference between apt-get virtualenv and pip virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, apt-get

What's the difference between the virtualenv from apt-get and that from pip? Are they interchangeable?

```
apt-get install virtualenv

The following extra packages will be installed:
  python-chardet-whl python-colorama-whl python-distlib-whl python-html5lib-whl python-pip-whl python-requests-whl
  python-setuptools-whl python-six-whl python-urllib3-whl python3-virtualenv
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-chardet-whl python-colorama-whl python-distlib-whl python-html5lib-whl python-pip-whl python-requests-whl
  python-setuptools-whl python-six-whl python-urllib3-whl python3-virtualenv virtualenv
```

Comment: apt-get is for system dependencies, pip is for python dependencies.

Comment: Didn't ask about that, I'm asking about the virtualenv(s)

Comment: Why does the Debian version have so many dependencies? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: @TomZych I didn't say you were, nor did I ever think of anyone that way. I'm simply asking a question and doing my best to keep it from getting off-topic. I was not asking about the differences between pip and apt-get. I was under the impression that StackOverflow encouraged to-the-point communication, rather than being caught up in politeness, please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At a high-level `apt` is something maintained by your system. Specifically anything in the debian family will use `apt` to manage things like drivers, compilers, things that require lower-level integration.

This means for things like `numpy` and `scipy` that require system-level integration with FORTRAN libraries, including the `pip` dependency won't actually work.

Some python packages that are tightly-linked with the system-level dependencies maintain `apt` packages that simply give you the full package all at once without having to coordinate between the two. The minus is that because Canonical's review process is pretty meticulous (as it should be) you will be getting, 9/10 a less-recent version of the library you're trying to use.

So, in short: you will often require `apt` packages to enable more recent `pip` installs, and while the same python dependencies may be available via `apt`, these libraries are typically much older and may not have required functionality.

A common workaround is to simply use the system dependencies from one of these packages rather than the full package. You can do this by use the `build-deps` flag. A common example given below:

```
apt-get build-dep python-scipy
pip install scipy
```

Which will actually give you the most up-to-date version of scipy while working within your virtualenv.

Answer (score 4):

`apt` or `apt-get` - installer debian similar distributions and install the packages in the directory `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

`pip install` - python package manager and install the packages in the directory `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Both directories are in the path of python that it is looking for modules import.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

Answer (score 1):

They use separate repositories, you can check what versions you're getting from `pip` through [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). As for `apt-get` you'll have to check your operating system's package manager version and source list to see what versions you're getting from there.