# What is the difference between PIP virtualenv and APT python-virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-venv

I am confused with below two commands to install `virtualenv`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
pip install virtualenv
```

Is it the same thing or what's the different between these two commands.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between apt-get virtualenv and pip virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862790/whats-the-difference-between-apt-get-virtualenv-and-pip-virtualenv)

Comment: Do add what you mean by 'different'.

Answer (score 1):

There is almost no difference if you only use system-wide Python. To be specific, `sudo apt install python-virtualenv` will install `virtualenv` for your system-wide Python. While `pip install virtualenv` will install `virtualenv` for your current environment.

That means using `pip install virtualenv`, you can install `virtualenv` install a conda environment, a virtual environment or even a portable environment.

For me, I mostly use `pip install virtualenv` as I mostly use a conda environment.